# How do I create an Ender Portal?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft PE just got the ender update, so how do I make the portal? I have tried using a 3x3 frame, but it still won't work.

Comment: If you're going to mark this question as a dupe as that other one, you may want to edit it to not say 'in creative'.

Answer (score 0):

To place them, they all have to be facing inwards. To place them, stand in the center of the circle and then place them. To check this, when you put in the eyes, the white dot on it should be pointing inwards. If not, destroy the block and place it again.

Answer (score -2):

You need to place **Ender eyes** on them.

Comment: You have likely been downvoted due to the short length of your answer. Consider adding more details or references.